# Unable to install Ubuntu on HP Pavilion DV6

Tags: 12.10, compatibility

I tried installing Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop (HP Pavilion DV6). Can you guys please tell me whether it is possible to install it or is 12.10 version of ubuntu compatible with it? I heard there problem is because of the graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

You can install either Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10 easily in your laptop and is compatible with it. The graphic card should not be the problem to install Ubuntu.